# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt {x}(\sqrt {x}+\sqrt {x-a})$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate: $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt {x}(\sqrt {x}+\sqrt {x-a})$

My Attempt:

$$=\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt {x} (\sqrt {x}+\sqrt {x-a})$$
It takes $\infty + \infty$ form when $x=\infty$. 
Now,
$$=\sqrt {x}(\sqrt {x} + \sqrt {x-a}) \times \dfrac {\sqrt {x} - \sqrt {x-a}}{\sqrt {x}-\sqrt {x-a}}$$
$$=\dfrac {\sqrt {x} (x-x+a)}{\sqrt {x}-\sqrt {x-a}}$$
$$=\dfrac {a\sqrt {x}}{\sqrt {x}-\sqrt {x-a}}$$

How do I proceed further?

Comment: you mean $+\infty$?

Comment: then the searched Limit is $+\infty$

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner, How? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: the answer is written already

Answer (score 1):

When $x \uparrow \infty$, both terms in the product tend to $+\infty$. So their product tends to $+\infty$.

In your parlance, $\infty + \infty = + \infty$.

Comment: You mean the answer is $+\infty$?

Comment: Yes, it is $+\infty$.

Comment: Then the answer for $\lim_{x\to \infty} \sqrt {x}(\sqrt {x+1} -\sqrt {x})$ , would also be $\infty $? Is it?

Comment: Your notation may be a bit fuzzy: since the limit above is understood to be $x \rightarrow + \infty$ (otherwise $\sqrt{x}$ is undefined), we get that you prefer to write $\infty$ instead of $+ \infty$. Make your choice and be consistent.

Comment: I asked if the answer for the ques. i showed in comments would be $+\infty $???

Comment: You asked about both $+\infty$ (first comment) and $\infty$ (third comment). My answer is $+\infty$, because the sign matters. (And it should matter in how you define the limit as well.)

Comment: but the answer for the question that I asked in third comment is $\dfrac {1}{2}$. So how is it possible?

Comment: Oh, I see.  You asked about another limit. Do not mix items, because it's confusing. You can post a different question.

Comment: @AlbertEinstein: Just take a calculator and plug in some reasonably large number (say x=1000000) into the two expressions, and hopefully you will get a feeling for why the results are completely different depending on whether you **add** or **subtract** the square roots.